# How to read the value of sensors on OS X?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, sensors

How can these the value of these sensors: CPU temperature, battery voltage, battery current, and fan speed, be read ?
I don't  find the right term in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for a method to get these from the command line check out [ioreg](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ioreg.8.html)

It might take a while to get the output in the format you want, but all the information is there.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to do it in C,but that's a starting point. At least I will know the right terms for what I'm looking for.

Comment: [smcFanControl](http://www.conscius.de/~eidac/software/page5/page5.html) includes its Objective-C source code for temperature and fan speeds

Comment: Do you know what output to grep for?